# How to create a directory in /var/run on startup?

Tags: 14.04, server, startup, init.d

I need to create a non-root owned directory in /var/run that a startup script in /etc/init.d will use. What is the proper way achieve this? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you made this startup script?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds No. It's distributed with the software I need to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do that on the fly. `/var/run/` is a tmpfs so recreated each boot.

From the init script:

- Create a directory inside `/var/run/` and change permissions to that user.
- Then specify to use `/var/run/mydaemon` rather than `/var/run`.

---

If you want examples on how to do this check (there are more):

```
/etc/init.d/ssh
/etc/init.d/bind9
/etc/init/dbus.conf
/etc/init/ssh.conf
/etc/init/cups.conf
```

All of them have some sort of `mkdir` in it. cups.conf:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/cups/certs
```

---

> **/etc/init/cups.conf**

```
pre-start script
    [ -x /usr/sbin/cupsd ]

    # load modules for parallel port support
    if [ -r /etc/default/cups ]; then
    . /etc/default/cups
    fi
    if [ "$LOAD_LP_MODULE" = "yes" -a -f /usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel \
     -a -f /proc/modules -a -x /sbin/modprobe ]; then
    modprobe -q -b lp || true
    modprobe -q -b ppdev || true
    modprobe -q -b parport_pc || true
    fi

    mkdir -p /var/run/cups/certs
    if [ -x /lib/init/apparmor-profile-load ]; then
    /lib/init/apparmor-profile-load usr.sbin.cupsd
    fi
end script
```

Comment: /var/run is mounted as tmpfs.

Comment: @prasopes yeah I realized it the second I posted it :D

Comment: @prasopes here ya go :-)